# AngularJS Global Variables - Services vs $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, service, global-variables

Say I have an array of data that I want to share globally. I can save it to `$rootScope` or use a `service`. I know that global variables are not great, so using a service seems like a better idea.

BUT, from [Angular FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq), they say

> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.

So which one should I use then?

Comment: I think they're saying, go ahead and use $rootScope for global data if you need to (but don't overdo it).  Use a service for global functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy,the FAQ says if it's only data, it's ok to use $rootScope , if you want to share methods or functions, use a service.

In my opinion, that FAQ is wrong since angularjs provides the `Module.value` method which is designed to store datas.So there's a bit of contradiction between the FAQ and angular api,which defines a method which only purpose is storing datas as a service.